# ZF translation forms

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-form, zend-form-element, zend-translate

I'm working with ZF2 and I'm using the translator.
In the config of my application I've added the translator to the service_manager factories, so it will be used by the ZF2 helpers.

This is how my translator config looks like:

```
'translator' => array(
    'locale' => 'nl_NL',
    'translation_file_patterns' => array(
        array(
            'type' => 'gettext',
            'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../language',
            'pattern' => '%s.mo',
        ),
    ),
),
```

In the module.php file of my application, I have the following piece of code in my onBootstrap method:

```
/**
 * Magic to determine the right locale to be used.
 * 
 * Check cookie
 * Check GET parameter
 * Check HOST (application can be used from several domain names)
 */ 

$translator = $serviceManager->get('translator');

// We have to change the current locale if $locale is not null.
if (!is_null($locale)) {          
    $translator->setLocale($locale);

    // The translate helper of the view has some problems with what we're doing.
    // So we'll manually add the translator with the correct locale to the view helper.
    $serviceManager->get('viewhelpermanager')->get('translate')->setTranslator($translator);
}
```

As you can see, I've already had some problems because of the locale modification in the onBootstrap method.

Now there are two things that can help me:
- Help me to find a way to re-inject the correct translator into the form helper;
- Help me to find a way to do this the way ZF2 likes or it should be done (My searches did not lead to a solution).

Hope you guys can help me out!

Answer (score 1):

It should work the same way for the form helper.

```
$serviceManager->get('ViewHelperManager')->get('form')->setTranslator($translator);
```

**EDIT**

And use the `MvcTranslator` service instead of `translator`.

```
if (!is_null($locale)) {
    $translator = $serviceManager->get('MvcTranslator');
    $translator->setLocale($locale);
    // ...
}
```

If you do that, you should not even need the `setTranslator()` calls.

Comment: You should try to use the `MvcTranslator` service instead of `translator`.

Comment: If I do this: $serviceManager->get('MvcTranslator')->setLocale($locale); $serviceManager->get('translator')->setLocale($locale); then it works... Is this what you mean? Because now I have to do $serviceManager->get('MvcTranslator')->setCache($cache); $serviceManager->get('translator')->setCache() as well.

Comment: Don't use the `translator` service at all. Only use the `MvcTranslator`.I'm adding the complete code to the original answer.

Comment: Unfortunatly this does not fix the problem.. if (!is_null($locale)) {             $translator = $serviceManager->get('MvcTranslator');            $translator->setLocale($locale); } still gives a non-translated form.

Answer (score 0):

use `MvcTranslator` instead of `translator`:

```
$translator = $serviceManager->get('MvcTranslator');
$translator->setLocale($locale);
$serviceManager->get('ViewHelperManager')
               ->get('translate')->setTranslator($translator);
```